# Apply distinct in concat query

Tags: postgresql

I have written a join query for three tables, concatenating the columns of these three tables. But in last table `keywords` column has only one value but while concatinating the value is repeated.

```
SELECT
  g.goal_id,
  concat(coalesce(rk.keyword, ''),
         coalesce(gr.description, ''),
         coalesce(cd.keywords, ''))
FROM goal g
  LEFT OUTER JOIN resource_keyword rk ON (g.creater_id = rk.refference_id AND
                                          g.creater_id = :userId)
  LEFT OUTER JOIN groups gr ON gr.creater_id = g.creater_id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN communication_detail cd ON cd.party_id = gr.creater_id
LIMIT 5
```

Actual Result :

```
      goal_id      concat

      296          noseDaily walk,sad,err
      296          Healthy is a goalDaily walk,sad,err
      296          Healthylife a healthy dayDaily walk,sad,err
      296          tasty foodDaily walk,sad,err
      296          healthygradeDaily walk,sad,err
```

Expected Result :

```
      goal_id       concat

      296          noseDaily walk,sad,err
      296          Healthy is a goalDaily walk
      296          Healthylife a healthy dayDaily walk
      296          tasty foodDaily walk
      296          healthygradeDaily walk
```

Here sad,err belong to the third table having only one value separated by commas, but it gets appended to each and every row.

Comment: Post the sample data to run the queries against

Comment: Why do you want it like this?

Comment: That is my requirement